# .tmp files appearing in Windows\Temp folder

Tags: windows

There is some program running that is creating .tmp files in my \Windows\Temp folder and filling up the hard drive.  How can I determine what program is doing that?  Is there some utility that I can run that tells me what program is writing to a files on disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sysinternals filemon will be the solution.

[FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx)

Update : I think it is replaced by Process Monitor.

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: Yes, it'd been replaced and that's what the tool will tell you too :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it really bothers you then create either a scheduled or startup task that runs:

```
del c:\windows\temp\*.* /F /Q /S
```

You may also want to do the same for \Local Settings\Temp

Comment: Whatever program is running is also hammering the disk, though. Clearing out the files creates additional disk access. If possible, it is much better to find out what is creating the garbage files.